# Isolate a factory/service object to an individual element's directives

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a factory service that is being shared by 2 attribute directives (named centerPage and keepleft). There are multiple elements that make use of one or both of these directives. Here's the code and then I'll explain the issue I'm having.

```
app.factory("style", function(){
    return{
        style: {}
    }
});

app.directive("centerPage", ['style', function (style) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;

        var boxW = 370;
        var boxH = 385;

        scope.style = style;
        scope.style.left = (winW / 2) - (boxW / 2);
        scope.style.top = (winH / 2) - (boxH / 2);
    }
}]);

app.directive("keepleft", ['style', function (style) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.style = style;
        scope.style.cursor = 'default';
        scope.style.transform = 'translateX(-60%)';
    }
}]);

<started-box center-page keepleft></started-box>

<action-box center-page></action-box>
```

The issue is that only one

> style

object is being shared among all elements. **Therefore, all the css from both directives is being applied to elements even when they only use 1 of the directives** (assuming another element on the page uses both directives).

**How can I isolate the scope so that the style object is being shared only among directives of an individual element?**

I don't want to create messy code here. It should hopefully just be a simple tweak to the scope. No messy controllers please.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is because of the shared object. You can modify your factory to return new object based on name.

```
app.factory("style", function(){
  var _cache = {};
  return function(name) {
    if (!_cache[name]) {
      _cache[name] = {};
    }
    return _cache[name];
  };
});
```

Then your directives can do this

```
scope.style = style(attrs.centerPage);
scope.style = style(attrs.keepleft);
```

And HTML

```
<started-box center-page="group1" keepleft="group1"></started-box>
<action-box center-page="group2"></action-box>
```

P/s: I think you can also mess around with `element`, IIRC each `element` is unique and has some kind of `id`, I just can't remember what and how to get that `id` (I have been away from angular for few months). When you can get `id` of the element, you can drop the whole `attrs` thing

Comment: I spent a lot of time messing with that answer but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It's not a syntax issue either. It's something more fundamental about the scope but I'm banging my head against the wall all day trying to figure it out :(

Comment: It sets the style correctly however the ng-style="$parent.style" that I have in the element template seems to be using both directives still. I think that's the issue now.

Comment: I don't know how you place your scope, but from what you are describing, it is probably the issue of nested scope. Basically if you use shared scope, the `style` attribute will be overwritten by the nested scope. It would be easier for me to see if you have a complete example setup in jsfiddle or similar service